# Exception:APM model error: problem with vector index

Tags: python, gekko

I'm new to using Gekko in Python.

While I run the following code, I got this error:

```
Exception:  @error: Vector Index
APM model error: problem with vector index
line number: 21
line string: 
p2>((0+((0+((v1)*([54.54545455])))+((v3)*([45.45454545]))))+((0+((v2)*([54.5454
  5455])))+((v4)*([45.45454545]))))
  non-integer value:    45.4545454500000     
  STOPPING..
```

with the following code :

```
from gekko import GEKKO

def Optimization_Approach(Processing_Time_Remote,Total_Time_local,Total_Time_Remote,Total_Energy_Consumption_Local,Total_Energy_Consumption_Remote,parameters):

number_of_users=parameters.number_of_users
number_of_tasks=parameters.number_of_tasks    
data_rate=parameters.available_data_rate
Input_Size_Task=parameters.input_size_for_task_users
Edge_Capability_Mobile=parameters.edge_capability_mobile_users
Bandwidth=data_rate*number_of_users # All available data rate
Edge_Server_Capability=parameters.edge_server_capability
Edge_Server_Caching_Storage=parameters.edge_server_storage_capability

#Create a python model object
m = GEKKO() 

#define parameter
B = m.Param(value=Bandwidth)
F_c=m.Param(value=Edge_Server_Capability)
F_s=m.Param(value=Edge_Server_Caching_Storage)

#define Variables 

x = m.Array(m.Var,(number_of_users,number_of_tasks))
y = m.Array(m.Var,(number_of_users,number_of_tasks))

#Constraint 1
m.Equation(B>=sum([sum([x[i][j]*data_rate for i in range(number_of_users)]) for j in range(number_of_tasks)]))
#Constraint 2
m.Equation(F_c>=sum([sum([x[i][j]*Edge_Capability_Mobile[i] for i in range(number_of_users)]) for j in range(number_of_tasks)]))
# Constraint 3
m.Equation(F_s>=sum([sum([x[i][j]*Input_Size_Task[i][j] for i in range(number_of_users)]) for j in range(number_of_tasks)]))

#define Objective
m.Obj(sum([sum([(y[i][j]*Processing_Time_Remote[i][j])+((1-y[i][j])*((1-x[i][j])*Total_Time_local+x[i][j]*Total_Time_Remote)) +((1-y[i][j])*((1-x[i][j])*Total_Energy_Consumption_Local+x[i][j]*Total_Energy_Consumption_Remote)) for i in range(number_of_users)]) for j in range(number_of_tasks)]))

#Solve Model
m.solve()
print('Results')
print(x)
print(y)
```

Please, can anyone help me?
In addition, how to make the variables in `m.array` binary?

Answer (score 1):

An Answer by Prof Hendregen

I can't reproduce your problem because it requires the inputs to your function. The error message is that one of your inequality expressions is using a list value [45.4545] instead of a number 45.4545 in the expression. You can resolve this by using the value `(x[0])` instead of the list `(x)`. If you put an [0] at the end of those lists, it will use just the value.

If you need to pass additional arguments when creating a variable array, you can use something like the following:

Option 1
Create a `numpy` array with the `m.Array` function:

```
y = m.Array(m.Var,4,lb=0,ub=1,integer=True)
```

See https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_methods.html?highlight=array

Option 2
Create a list of variables with a list comprehension:

```
y = [m.Var(lb=0,ub=1,integer=True) for i in range(4)]
```

Option 3
Alternatively, you can create an empty list (y) and append binary values to that list.

```
y = []
for i in range(3):
    y.append(m.Var(lb=0,ub=1,integer=True)
```

Comment: Janus, thanks for posting another helpful discussion thread from the e-mail group.